# Toggle image on click arrows on image using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create the ability for users to see the product rollover image on click the arrows on image.

Basically image will toggle on click of the side arrows on image.

**Is their any js library or script available that allows to achieve this functionality ?**

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/).

The setup is really easy:
include this in the head of your document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

than add your images to the swiper-slide elements

```
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Image 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Image 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Image 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

set the desired size

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

and finally initialize it within a script tag

```
<script>
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
})
</script>
```

all of this is really well explained in the [guide](https://swiperjs.com/get-started/)

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer, let me check this.

Comment: This does not provide infinite image rollover functionality.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by infinite image rollover? Do you have an example?